# i want to parse a file csv and display the data in a table using Angular 2

Tags: angular, file, csv, file-upload, display

i'm new on angular 2/4 and i want do parse a csv file and display the iformations in a table.
i tried sth but the data  get displayed in console i want them in the web page in table.
if anyone can help me?

```
 selectFile(files: FileList) {
console.log(files);
if(files && files.length > 0) {
   let file : File = files.item(0); 

     let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsText(file);
     reader.onload = (e) => {
        let csv: string = reader.result;
        console.log(csv);
     }
  }
```

this function display me the data in console how can i change it in html

```
upload() {
  this.progress.percentage = 0;

    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0)
    this.uploadservice.pushFileToStorage(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
        this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
      }
    })

    this.selectedFiles = undefined
}
```

And this function for the button upload file and when i added the selectFile function the button didn't work again

Answer (score 4):

First you need to convert csv file data into a readable format. for that i would suggest to use a csv parser Papaparse.
install papaparse with `npm install papaparse` [go to site](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#strings)

you can parse a string as well as a file also.

for a string according to your code

```
selectFile(files: FileList) {
console.log(files);
if(files && files.length > 0) {
    let file : File = files.item(0); 

    let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        let csv: string = reader.result;
        Papa.parse(csv,{
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            complete: (result,file) => {
              console.log(result);
              this.dataList = result.data;
            }
         })
    }
  }
}
```

once you assign data into dataList

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> headers</td>
            <td> headers</td>
            <td> headers</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let record of dataList">
            <td> {{record.fieldName1}} </td>
            <td> {{record.fieldName2}} </td>
            <td> {{record.fieldName3}} </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have done this task with online editor its works perfectly 
[sample code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csv-parser)
hope this works for you ....

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work. the obj is unknown i don't know why

Comment: i had to use obj to get results.data values to out of asynchronous method. if you can tell the error then get i can help you.

Comment: I have edit the answer and added link for online example please check

Comment: yes it works for me thank you, i have a question ! why we declared the obj : AppComponent out of the class  ? what's the reason

Comment: yes, that approach is bad, so i changed it better way please check the link now.

Comment: Is this fixed ?